# Adapter_Android listview

Tags: android

My problem is that I have two classes and I want to show them in a `ListView`. I want to merge between those ones into one list view  in `AsyncTask`, there is my code and I need a help.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            twitt = Services.getTwitterTv();
            twittns = Services.getTwitter();


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            for (Twitter twitts : twitt) 
                for(Twitter twittn: twittns)

                {
                    System.out.println(twitts.getTexte());
                    System.out.println(twittn.getTexte());

                }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            twitt.addAll(Services.getTwitter());
            twitt.addAll(Services.getTwitterTv());



            TwitterAdapter adapter = new TwitterAdapter(TwitterTv.this, R.layout.twitts_item, twitt );
            TwitterAdapter adapter2 = new TwitterAdapter(TwitterTv.this, R.layout.twitts_item, twittns );

            twitterlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            twitterlist.setAdapter(adapter2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: your sound like Expandable listview ? yes? no? Elaborate the question

Comment: i parse two classes , and i want the result of this classes on a listview just it , i can display one class but for two classes i didn't know how to do it .

Comment: i try it but nothing happened :s

Answer (score 0):

So marge the date and in your `addapter` ask what data is it. If its `data1` then infalte view number one, if it's `data2` then inflate view `number2`.

Then just populate the view with the data and you are done.